# MySQL: multiple search/select queries at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question on how to go about the next phase of a project I am working on.

Phase I:

create a php script that scraped directory for all .txt file..
Open/parse each line, explode into array...
Loop through array picking out pieces of data that were needed and INSERTING everything into the database (120+ .txt files & 100k records inserted)..

this leads me to my next step,

Phase II:

I need to take a 'list' of several 10's of thousand of numbers..
loop through each one, using that piece of data (number) as the search term to QUERY the database.. if a match is found I need to grab a piece of data in a different column of the same record/row..

General thoughts/steps I plan to take

1. scrape directory to find 'source' text file.
2. open/parse 'source file'.... line by line...
3. explode each line by its delimiting character.. and grab the 'target search number'
4. dump each number into a 'master list' array...
5. loop through my 'master list' array.. using each number in my search (SELECT) statement..
6. if a match is found, grab a piece of data in another column in the matching/returned row (record)...
7. output this data.. either to screen or .txt file (havent decided on that step yet,..most likely text file through each returned number on a new line)

Specifics:

I am not sure how to go about doing a 'multiple' search/select statement like this?

How can I do multiple SELECT statements each with a unique search term?  and also collect the returned column data?

is the DB fast enough to return the matching value/data in a loop like this?  Do I need to wait/pause/delay somehow for the return data before iterating through the loop again?

thanks!

current function I am using/trying:

this is where I am currently:

```
$harNumArray2 = implode(',', $harNumArray);
//$harNumArray2 = '"' . implode('","', $harNumArray) . '"';
$query = "SELECT guar_nu FROM placements WHERE har_id IN ($harNumArray2)";
echo $query;

$match = mysql_query($query);
//$match = mysql_query('"' . $query . '"');
$results = $match;
echo("<BR><BR>");
print_r($results);
```

I get these outputs respectively:

Array ( [0] => sample_source.txt )

Total FILES TO GRAB HAR ID's FROM: 1

TOAL HARS FOUND IN ALL FILES: 5
SELECT guar_nu FROM placements WHERE har_id IN ("108383442","106620416","109570835","109700427","100022236")

&

Array ( [0] => sample_source.txt )

Total FILES TO GRAB HAR ID's FROM: 1

TOAL HARS FOUND IN ALL FILES: 5
SELECT guar_nu FROM placements WHERE har_id IN (108383442,106620416,109570835,109700427,100022236)

Where do I stick this to actually execute it now?

thanks!

update:

this code seems to be working 'ok'.. but I dont understand on how to handle the retirned data correctly..  I seem to only be outputting (printing) the last variable/rows data..instead of the entire list..

```
$harNumArray2 = implode(',', $harNumArray);
//$harNumArray2 = '"' . implode('","', $harNumArray) . '"';
//$query = "'SELECT guar_num FROM placements WHERE har_id IN ($harNumArray2)'";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT har_id, guar_num FROM placements WHERE har_id IN (" . $harNumArray2 . ")")
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT har_id, guar_num FROM placements WHERE har_id IN (0108383442,0106620416)")
or die(mysql_error());  

// store the record of the "example" table into $row
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);

/*
while($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ){
    // do something
    echo("something <BR>");
}
*/

// Print out the contents of the entry 
echo("TOTAL ROWS RETURNED : " . $numRows . "<BR>");
echo "HAR ID: ".$row['har_id'];
echo " GUAR ID: ".$row['guar_num'];
```

How do I handle this returned data properly?

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried doing anything yourself yet? Can we see some code? I just can't get a 100% clear picture of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*I am not sure how to go about doing a 'multiple' search/select statement like this?*

With regards to a multiple select, (and I'll assume that you're using MySQL) you can perform that simply with the "[IN" keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

for example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YOUR_TABLE 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN (LIST, OF, SEARCH, VALUES, SEPARATED, BY COMMAS)
```

**EDIT**: following your updated code in the question.

just a point before we go on... you should try to avoid the mysql_ functions in PHP for new code, as they are about to be deprecated.  Think about using the generic PHP DB handler PDO or the newer mysqli_ functions.  More help on choosing the "right" API for you is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

*How do I handle this returned data properly?*

For handling more than one row of data (which you are), you should use a loop.  Something like the following should do it (and my example will use the mysqli_ functions - which are probably a little more similar to the API you've been using):

```
  $mysqli   = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
  mysqli_select_db($mysqli, "YOUR_DB");

  // make a comma separated list of the $ids.
  $ids = join(", ", $id_list);

  // note: you need to pass the db connection to many of these methods with the mysqli_ API
  $results  = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT har_id, guar_num FROM placements WHERE har_id IN ($ids)");
  $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($results);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    echo "HAR_ID: ". $row["har_id"]. "\tGUAR_NUM: " . $row["guar_num"] . "\n";
  }
```

Please be aware that this is very basic (and untested!) code, just to show the bare minimum of the steps.   :)

Comment: Thanks.. so can I 'build' this in a loop? ad have it return a value in each record where a number is found/matched?

Thanks

Comment: like this:

<code>
SELECT 'guar_num' 
FROM placements 
WHERE har_id IN ('build by list of numbers here...there are 1000's')
</code>

Comment: `SELECT 'guar_num' 
FROM placements 
WHERE har_id IN ('build by list of numbers here...there are 1000's')`

Comment: this is where I am currently:
`
$harNumArray2 = implode(',', $harNumArray);
 //$harNumArray2 = '"' . implode('","', $harNumArray) . '"';
 $query = "SELECT guar_nu FROM placements WHERE har_id IN ($harNumArray2)";
 echo $query;
 `

Comment: this is where I am currently:
<pre><code>
$harNumArray2 = implode(',', $harNumArray);
 //$harNumArray2 = '"' . implode('","', $harNumArray) . '"';
 $query = "SELECT guar_nu FROM placements WHERE har_id IN ($harNumArray2)";
 echo $query;
 </pre></code>

Comment: sorry still getting the hang of it here, I have updated the first post

Comment: its hard to get used to how this works (no enter, no edits after a few minutes...)  code updated in first post

Comment: well the WHERE IN was the right direction/answer.  Just not clear on how to get the mass data 'out' of the returned data/query?

Anyone still around?

thanks!

Comment: thanks!.. that worked great!
I do have another question/problem though.. in the $array Im passing in as my list of search words (numbers) in the SELECT query...

Im using the WHERE .. IN() approach...  but if one of the terms/indexes I am passing to be used as a search/select value is NOT there (missing form the DB, returns no match)... how can I see that?  I am currently getting a list back of the found/matches.. but I nee at least a original value or -    -  to be returned for the values..something to keep the place holder/order correct

thanks!

Comment: I am need to keep the 'order' so if 'not returned, need to be a blank or replaced by something?  I'll start a new post as suggested.  Not sure how to title it?  Handling returned (empty) WHERE/IN data?
if I had a better understanding.. I could search by some search terms

Thanks

Comment: follow question/post is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530806/mass-where-in-statement-how-to-handle-empty-returned-data-as-well-matches

(hopefully not as messy as I made this one)  :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answers your question but I think you're asking about sub-queries. They're pretty straightforward and just look something like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE id = (SELECT num FROM tbl2 WHERE id = 1);
```

That will only work if there is one unique value to that second subquery. If it returns multiple rows it will return a parse error. If you have to select multiple rows research JOIN statements. This can get you started

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: sorry if I wasnt clear.

I have a list of 'numbers' in an array. I need to loop through this array searching the DB for each of these numbers to see if its in there.

If it is... I need to grab the value in the matching number's record (the next column where this number is found)

Comment: I have updated my code in the first post... I think everything is ok.. I am just not clear on handle the returned data..  seems Im only printing out the LAST variable info..instead of the entire list..?  Do I need to push to an array then loop through that as output?