# MASS WHERE/IN statement, how to handle empty/returned data as well matches?

Tags: php, mysql, match, where-clause, empty-list

I have a question I hope you can help me with..

I am doing a large SELECT statement using WHERE/IN and passing in an $array for all the 'search terms' to be used.

quick example.. (although in the end the $array is much larger)

```
$harNumArray = (0100001943,0100001944,0100002392,0100007414,0100012110,0100015761,0100015835);
$harNumArray2 = implode(',', $harNumArray);
$results  = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT har_id, guar_num FROM placements WHERE har_id IN ($harNumArray2)");

//**outputting the matches values/data from the search (select)**

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    //echo "HAR_ID: ". $row["har_id"]. "\tGUAR_NUM: " . $row["guar_num"] . "\r\n<BR>";
    echo $row["har_id"]. "\t" . $row["guar_num"] . "\r\n<BR>";
    fwrite($fh, $row["har_id"] . "\t" . $row["guar_num"] . "\r\n");
}
```

and this works fine/great (*thanks msturdy for tip)... 'when' there IS a match.. if there is not a match..nothing is returned.

However.. if for example the first value in the $harNumArray (index 0) was NOT found in the database...
nothing is returned in the $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results loop...

ONLY found numbers.. and their matching/associated data that was pulled form the DB with it..

I’d like it to be like this still:

- 0100001943^- //missing/hot found number (entry) in the DB but still
  using original search term in first position)
- 0100001944^0123467894
- 0100002392^0011122234
- 0100007414^0002130567
- 0100012110^0000045432
- 0100015761^0001000045
- 0100015835^0998775233

Or like this would be acceptable (but above layout would be better):

- -^-  //missing/hot found number (entry) in the DB
- 0100001944^0123467894
- 0100002392^0011122234
- 0100007414^0002130567
- 0100012110^0000045432
- 0100015761^0001000045
- 0100015835^0998775233

If the first number in the $harNumArray array is not found in the WHERE/IN SELECT.. it doesnt return anything  (which makes sense)..

however.. I 'need' to account for the non-matches..  and insert a blank (or something).. to keep the spacing/order of the final 'list' (text file)

How can I go about doing this?

thanks!

**EDIT::**

here is current state of code: (still returns no matches)

@Cal

```
//stack overflow approach:
    //format array data
    $harNumArray2 = "'" . implode("','", $harNumArray) . "'";    //single quotes
    //$harNumArray2 = implode(',', $harNumArray);  //no quotes
    //$harNumArray2 = '"' . implode('","', $harNumArray) . '"';  //double quotes
    //print_r("ARRAY CHECK: " . $harNumArray2);

    $results = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT har_id, guar_num FROM placements WHERE har_id IN ($harNumArray2) ORDER BY har_id ASC") or die(mysql_error());
    //$results = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT har_id, guar_num FROM placements WHERE har_id IN (" . $harNumArray2 . ") ORDER BY har_id ASC") or die(mysql_error());

    echo("<BR>");
    print_r("SELECT har_id, guar_num FROM placements WHERE har_id IN ($harNumArray2)");
    echo("<BR>");

    $rows = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $rows[$row['har_id']] = $row;
    }
    foreach ($harNumArray as $id){
        if (isset($rows[$id])){
            //... do something with $rows[$id]
            print_r($rows[$id] . "<BR>");

        }else{
            //... no match for $id
            print_r("....no match....");
            echo("<BR>");
        }
    }
```

still no match is returned... no matter single quotes, no quotes or double quotes..

stumped?

thanks

**UPDATE II:**

@Cal-

ok I ran the code you supplied..

this was my output:

Array ( [har_id] => 000100007537 [guar_num] => 0000676798 ) Array ( [har_id] => 000100007538 [guar_num] => 0000676798 ) Array ( [har_id] => 000100007539 [guar_num] => 0000676798 ) Array ( [har_id] => 000100007768 [guar_num] => 0000675266 ) Array ( [har_id] => 000100007769 [guar_num] => 0000675266 )

HAR_ID in DB = varchar(12)

GUAR_NUM in DB = varchar(12)

if I leave OFF the quotes in the #results query.. I get a return on data.. (but no matter what.. no matches found)

Comment: 1. You forgot `array(` at `$harNumArray = (` 2. Do you realize the numbers are INTS, so the leading `0` will be removed?

Answer (score 0):

Perform your query:

```
$harNumArray = array(
    '0100001943',
    '0100001944',
    '0100002392',
    '0100007414',
    '0100012110',
);
$harNumArray2 = "'".implode("','", $harNumArray)."'";
$results = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT har_id, guar_num FROM placements WHERE har_id IN ($harNumArray2)");
```

Then build a map of your results:

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $rows[$row['har_id']] = $row;
}
```

Then you can loop over your IDs checking for matches:

```
foreach ($harNumArray as $id){

    if (isset($rows[$id])){
        ... do something with $rows[$id]
    }else{
        ... no match for $id
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

It sounds like your query is not returning anything. Run this code:

```
$results = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT har_id, guar_num FROM placements LIMIT 5");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) print_r($row);
```

And then update your question with the output. It sounds like your database does not contain quite what you think.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, I must be implementing it wrong?  (everything comes back not found) How do you post code in comments?  I see help says 'code' but not clue what that means?  use apostrophe's and denote code blocks?

thanks

Comment: Your problem is probably related to the types you're using in the database. If `har_id` is actually a string (which it looks like it might be from your examples) then you need to quote the IDs in your first array. If they are really numbers, removing the leading zeros.

Comment: You might be right.. they are both varchar(12)

Here is what Im using now:  (what are 'backticks'? And how do you do them?)



   `foreach($harNumArray as $harNum) {
     $results  = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT guar_num FROM placements WHERE har_id = $harNum");
     if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
      $guarNum = $row["guar_num"];
     }else {
      $guarNum = "-";
     }
  //echo $harNum . "\t" . $guarNum . "\r\n<BR>";
     fwrite($fh, $harNum . "\t" . $guarNum . "\r\n");
 }`

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you how to use strings. The backtick key is to the left of your 1 key. If this still does not work for you, add `print_r($rows);` at the end and then add that output to your question.

Comment: (code post attempt) (no coloring like your post?>)

this seems to be working.. but man is it SLOW

    `foreach($harNumArray as $harNum) {
     $results  = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT guar_num FROM placements WHERE har_id = $harNum");
     if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
      $guarNum = $row["guar_num"];
     }else {
      $guarNum = "-";
     }
  //echo $harNum . "\t" . $guarNum . "\r\n<BR>";
     fwrite($fh, $harNum . "\t" . $guarNum . "\r\n");
 }`

Comment: There is no need to do that - you can do it with one query instead of one-per-ID, using the code in my answer.

Comment: ok.. I'll try it your way.. see if it works out any faster/better.

thanks

Comment: ok.. well I'dd love to NOT have to do all those selects individually..but I cant your approach to work?  (still cant post full colored code)

Comment: `$harNumArray2 = "'".implode("','", $harNumArray);
 $results = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT har_id, guar_num FROM placements WHERE har_id IN (" . $harNumArray2 . ") ORDER BY har_id ASC");
 
 $rows = array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
     $rows[$row['har_id']] = $row;
 }
 foreach ($harNumArray as $id){
  if (isset($rows[$id])){
         //... do something with $rows[$id]
   print_r($rows[$id] . "<BR>");
     }else{
         //... no match for $id
   print_r("....no match....");
     }
 }`

Comment: I get this error:  Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\ahc_guarSearch\guarMatch_audit2.php on line 92

which is this line: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {`

Comment: It looks like your query is failing. Did you disable error messages perhaps? Check the line starting `$harNumArray2 =` to check it has the final closing quote

Comment: I guess Im just getting more and more confused on what Im supposed to do with all these changes?





this is where it stands as of now??  any ideas on what Im doing wrong still?   Thanks!

edit: cant even post a small snippet of code? too long? (jeez this help board is difficult to deal with)

Comment: code:
`$harNumArray2 = "'" . implode("','", $harNumArray) . "'"; 
 //$harNumArray2 = implode(',', $harNumArray);
 //$harNumArray2 = '"' . implode('","', $harNumArray) . '"'; `
doesnt matter how I format the array to pass into it it seems


singles, doubles..no quotes..

Comment: final part:

`$results = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT har_id, guar_num FROM placements WHERE har_id IN (" . $harNumArray2 . ") ORDER BY har_id ASC");
 
 $rows = array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
     $rows[$row['har_id']] = $row;
 }
 foreach ($harNumArray as $id){
  if (isset($rows[$id])){
         //... do something with $rows[$id]
   print_r($rows[$id] . "<BR>");
     }else{
         //... no match for $id
   print_r("....no match....");
     }
 }`

Comment: well I isolated the problem to here:

`while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
     $rows[$row['har_id']] = $row;
  echo("<BR>");
  echo(".");
 }`


Doesnt even look to be executing at all (no echo statements on screen)  but Im not sure WHY?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some test code at the bottom so we can  see what's in your database. Please run that and update your question.

Comment: Check that the IDs you're using in your code (the contents of `$harNumArray`) exactly match the IDs in your database, with the correct number of leading zeros. If the query is not returning any matches then it looks like you're not using valid values for `har_id` in the query.